# JS Declaración múltiple de variables

Tags: javascript, variables

Me gustaría saber si es correcto hacer una declaración de este tipo

```
var a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = 666;
```

Se que se puede hacer del siguiente modo pero lo encuentro repetitivo:

```
var a1=666, a2=666, a3=666, a4=666;
```

Podríais recomendarme alguna web que hable bien de la declaración de variables mas allá del simple `var nombre = valor`?

Mil gracias!

Comment: Aquí se explica el tema que tratas: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var Añadir que la manera en la que declaras las variables de tu primera declaración es correcta.

Comment: Es cuestión de gustos, ya que ambas formas son legibles. Además dependerá del caso, porque si es importante que las 4 variables se inicialicen igual, entonces el primer modo te asegura que cualquier cambio siempre afecta a todas.